# Regex for text between last valid parenthesis

Tags: java, regex

I need to use regex for following text. The parenthesis are not nested.

```
{ ... bla ... {text} jdjdj ... { kdkdkdkd aaa { abc }
```

if I use `\{(.*?)\}` then there is two  groups:

```
... bla ... {text
kdkdkdkd aaa { abc
```

But I need

```
text
abc
```

Is it possible to write such Regex in Java ?

**EDIT**: The actually parenthesis are `@{` and `}@~enc~`

Actual string:

```
@{ ... bla ... @{text}@~enc~ jdjdj ... @{ kdkdkdkd aaa @{ abc }@~enc~
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Case 1. Single-character delimiters

You need to use a [**negated character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^{}]`:

```
\{([^{}]*)}
```

The `[^{}]` character class matches any character but `{` and `}`.

[Java demo](http://ideone.com/UBp9ey):

```
String s = "{ ... bla ... {text} jdjdj ... { kdkdkdkd aaa { abc }";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{([^{}]*)}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1).trim()); 
}
```

Note that you can use [**`String#trim()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) to get rid of trailing/leading whitespace in your captures.

## Case 2. Multi-character delimiters

To match text between multi-character delimiters, you can use a [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?s)@\\{((?:(?!@\\{|}@~enc~).)*)}@~enc~");
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [another demo](http://ideone.com/nPp2M3). The `(?s)` modifier (equal to setting the `Pattern.DOTALL` flag) makes a `.` match newlines, too.

NB: Do not forget to escape the `{` symbol in Java regex, and you do not have to escape `}`.

Comment: [`{\s*([^{}]*?)\s*}`](https://regex101.com/r/yQ6aX0/1) if OP don't want spaces in the matches.

Comment: @Tushar: I believe in Java, it is OK to just use `trim()`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was searching. [`trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim())

Comment: Hey thank you! Is it possible to use negated character class for more than one character string. Because my parenthesis are `@{` and `}@~enc~`.

Comment: @Tony: You need a tempered greedy token, and that does sound like a new question :) You can use `"(?s)@\\{((?:(?!@\\{|}@~enc~).)*)}@~enc~"`

Comment: Ok, I can answer here, no need. Just edit the question with correct data.

Comment: Just next time do not oversimplify the requirements and the sample input. For regex, it  might be crucial.